# Extract required values from a text corresponding to given string matches

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, text, python-re

I have the following string.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                         int. normalized  values  of  :                      *
*                         ---------------------------                         *
*                      % of irradiance at ground level                        *
*     % of direct  irr.    % of diffuse irr.    % of enviro. irr              *
*               0.488               0.418               0.093                 *
*                       reflectance at satellite level                        *
*     atm. intrin. ref.   background  ref.  pixel  reflectance                *
*               0.127               0.146               0.170                 *
*                                                                             *
*                         int. absolute values of                             *
*                         -----------------------                             *
*                      irr. at ground level (w/m2/mic)                        *
*     direct solar irr.    atm. diffuse irr.    environment  irr              *
*             592.299             507.010             113.283                 *
*                      rad at satel. level (w/m2/sr/mic)                      *
*     atm. intrin. rad.    background  rad.    pixel  radiance                *
*              58.837              67.355              78.685                 *
*                                                                             *
*                                                                             *
*                      sol. spect (in w/m2/mic)                               *
*                                2054.457                                     *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************
```

I tried to extract values corresponding to "direct solar irr.","atm. diffuse irr."and "environment  irr".

```
import re

def extract_values(text):
    pattern = r"direct solar irr\.\s*atm. diffuse irr\.\s*environment irr\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)"
    match = re.search(pattern, text)
    if match:
       return {
            "direct solar irr.": match.group(1),
            "atm. diffuse irr.": match.group(2),
            "environment irr.": match.group(3)
        }
```

But it produces None.

Could someone help me ?

Edit: Trying using BeautifulSoup:

`enter code here`def extract_values(text):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

# Get all text elements
lines = [line.strip() for line in soup.get_text().splitlines() if line.strip() != ""]

# Identify the line after the "direct solar irr." label
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "direct solar irr." in line:
        # Look for the next line with a number
        for subsequent_line in lines[i+1:]:
            if re.search(r'\d', subsequent_line):  # Check if the line has a digit
                values = subsequent_line.split()
                return {
                    "direct solar irr.": float(values[0]),
                    "atm. diffuse irr.": float(values[1]),
                    "environment irr.": float(values[2])
                }
```

direct_solar_irr = extract_values(text)
direct solar irr.": float(values[0]),
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '*'

edit 3:
[image]

Comment: I definitely prefer your beautifulSoup method, just need to use `values[1]`, `values[2]`, `values[3]` in order to skip over the first asterisk

Comment: Your data seems to have a fixed structure in which case there's no need to search for any strings/patterns because you *know* which line the values are on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regular pattern I designed. It is correct to apply this example, but I am not sure whether it can be applied to your specific scenario. This is actually a regular matching issue, not a Python code issue.

```
text = """
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                         int. normalized  values  of  :                      *
*                         ---------------------------                         *
*                      % of irradiance at ground level                        *
*     % of direct  irr.    % of diffuse irr.    % of enviro. irr              *
*               0.488               0.418               0.093                 *
*                       reflectance at satellite level                        *
*     atm. intrin. ref.   background  ref.  pixel  reflectance                *
*               0.127               0.146               0.170                 *
*                                                                             *
*                         int. absolute values of                             *
*                         -----------------------                             *
*                      irr. at ground level (w/m2/mic)                        *
*     direct solar irr.    atm. diffuse irr.    environment  irr              *
*             592.299             507.010             113.283                 *
*                      rad at satel. level (w/m2/sr/mic)                      *
*     atm. intrin. rad.    background  rad.    pixel  radiance                *
*              58.837              67.355              78.685                 *
*                                                                             *
*                                                                             *
*                      sol. spect (in w/m2/mic)                               *
*                                2054.457                                     *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************
"""

import re

def extract_values(text):
    # pattern = r"direct solar irr\.\s*atm. diffuse irr\.\s*environment irr\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)"
    pattern = r"direct solar irr\.\s*atm\. diffuse irr\.\s*environment  irr.*\n.*?\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)"
    match = re.search(pattern, text)
    # print(match.groups())
    if match and match.groups():
       return {
            "direct solar irr.": match.group(1),
            "atm. diffuse irr.": match.group(2),
            "environment irr.": match.group(3)
        }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = extract_values(text)
    print(data)
```

Need to find the rules,
Will your data definitely be below this string of text?
I understand that if it is really below, it can be extracted in this way. Even if you have a text with multiple lines, this set of data can also be extracted in this way, but the only consideration is performance issues, which may require more precise scenarios.

```
    lines = text.split('\n')
    data_index = [i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if 'direct solar irr.    atm. diffuse irr.    environment  irr' in line]
    data_index = data_index[0] if data_index else None
    if data_index is None:
        raise ValueError
    value_line = lines[data_index+1].strip("*").strip()
    for v in value_line.split():
        print(v)
```

Comment: yes, you have made it working. However, research seems so complex...what could be other straight forward method ?

Comment: @mark We need to determine the pattern. If we look at it from another perspective, is your data relatively stable or accurate? For example, if I am in this data, the data you need will be below your text, then I will cut it into lines. Array, and then pass a fixed character, whether it is in the tuple of the array, and find the corresponding index, then the data you need will be in the line next to the found index, and then extract the data

Comment: yes, this text data is stable, it is generated by `subprocess.run` when running the radiative-transfer code (6S). I need to extract the required values from the text.

Comment: @mark Well, to make extracting data more straight-forward, ask whoever is providing you the data to use a standardized text file format like CSV or JSON (or otherwise use an Excel file).

Comment: @mark I edited a new method. For unstructured text, you need to extract information and find patterns through analysis, such as regular matching or ruby and other methods. If the data segment is relatively accurate and stable, you can Files are processed line by line through Python, but if it is a large number of log parsing, etc., it is recommended to use third-party tools that may be more stable and efficient.

Comment: @chrisfang Oh, your 2nd answer is the best (I think) . It is more straightforward and should be much faster too

Comment: @mark I would caution against assuming one method is faster than the other until you have run a timing benchmark of both methods.

Answer (score 2):

The data appears to conform to a well-defined structure and if that's the case then the values you're interested in are on a particular line which simplifies to:

```
DSI = 'direct solar irr.'
ADI = 'atm. diffuse irr.'
EI = 'environment irr.'

def extract_values(text):
    _, dsi, adi, ei, _ = text.splitlines()[16].split()
    return {
        DSI: dsi,
        ADI: adi,
        EI: ei
    }
```

If, for some reason, you can't go directly to a particular line then you can search for the line that contains 'direct solar irr.' then you know that the values you're interested in are on the next line

```
def extract_values(text):
    for line in (lines := iter(text.splitlines())):
        if DSI in line:
            _, dsi, adi, ei, _ = next(lines).split()
            return {
                DSI: dsi,
                ADI: adi,
                ADI: ei,
            }
```

Yet another option is to search the entire string for the key value then just split the lines that follow

```
def extract_values(text):
    if (offset := text.find(DSI)) >= 0:
        _, dsi, adi, ei, _ = text[offset:].splitlines()[1].split()
        return {DSI: dsi, ADI: adi, EI: ei}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
pattern = r"direct solar irr\.\s*atm. diffuse irr\.\s*environment  irr\s*\*\n\*\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)"
```

See [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/2LjR6L/1) for a detailed break-down.